# How to validate all fields using WPF MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

If I click the Create button, it checks that all fields are empty and validate or not. If anything is missing, it shows a validation message.

View:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="validationErrorTemplate">
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="textblockErrorTooltip" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10 0 10 0" />
        </Style>
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <Border Height="Auto"
            Margin="5,0,0,0"
            Background="#DC000C"
            CornerRadius="3"
            DockPanel.Dock="right">
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textblockErrorTooltip}" DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                       Text="{Binding ElementName=customAdorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
        </Border>
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="customAdorner">
            <Border BorderBrush="#DC000C" BorderThickness="1.3" />
        </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>     

<TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="UserName"  Name="txtuserName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width="163" Canvas.Left="426" Canvas.Top="172"/>
<TextBox MaxLength="10" Name="txtUserName" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationErrorTemplate}" Text="{Binding MemberModelObj.MemberName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" FontSize="18"  Style="{StaticResource textblockErrorTooltip}" GotFocus="TextUserName_GotFocus" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="24" Width="370" ></TextBox>
<TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="FullName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width="102" Canvas.Left="426" Canvas.Top="241" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.275,0.967"/>
<TextBox FontSize="18" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationErrorTemplate}" GotFocus="TextFull_GotFocus"  Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Text="{Binding MemberModelObj.MemberFullName,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="24" Width="367" Name="txtFirstName" />
```

I'm using `IDataErrorInfo` interface in Model Class.

Model:

```
public string this[string columnName]
{
    set { columnName = value; }
    get
    {
        switch (columnName)
        {
            case "MemberName":
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(MemberName))
                {
                    result = "! Please Enter a User Name";
                }
                else if (MemberName.Length >= 30)
                {
                    result = "! Name can not be longer than 30 characters.";
                }
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

It validates only before button click. But I excepted it after the button command or click event.

Comment: There is no button called create button in your code.

Comment: This is my button command  public void CreateMember(object Sender)
        {
           Task.Run(() => AddNewMember()).Wait();
        }

Answer (score 1):

You could set the properties that need to be validated as defaults, like empty string in your `AddNewMember()` method. That would trigger Validation. Or create a public `Validate()` method on your object that implements `IDataErrorInfo` interface, where that method would validate everything. So when you create a new member, call the `Validate()` method after construction should do it.